# Background not positioned properly, text not importing, rollover effects?

Tags: html, css, font-face, rollover-effect

Hey guys I'm still working on the same web mockup design for a friend and I am trying to figure out a few things so I know for the future.

First off, the background image is not positioned properly (and I know if I change it from fixed it will be, but I want that scrolling effect). Code is:

```
.jumbotron {
background:url("http://i.imgur.com/5zm8SAo.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
height: 500px;
}
```

If I mess with the background size, then the dimensions don't fit with the website.

1. I uploaded a font from my computer (I don't have a server set up yet) to a public font generator website as an OTF file, and I had it running on my computer when I was working on it last night but now from my office computer, the font shows up at default.  Is there a workaround? or do I need a server?
2. I want to add some rollover effects to the pictures at the bottom, enlarge in general them a bit, fade out and add text, similar to the reigningchamp website (scroll to bottom, not enough rep to post two links?!?) So this code works:

   ```
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class = "grow">  
               <div class="thumbnail">
                   <img src="#" />
                 </div>
               </div>
           </div>
   .grow {
   display: inline-block;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
   transition-duration: 0.3s;
   -webkit-transition-property: transform;
   transition-property: transform;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    .grow:hover, .grow:focus, .grow:active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    }
   ```

Also since I am using the bootstrap framework, when I try to enlarge the thumbnails from calling the class thumbnail, nothing changes how do I make the images bigger but still in the line they are in?

1. And One LAST Thing is a general question on how to make the formatting of the site adjust to browser window, mobile, etc. so the font doesnt run on the page or the logo at the top gets misplaced? This might have to do with javascript which I've been working on learning through codeacademy(but so far its all these games and random functions, not website functionality). If you make the window smaller, the nav menu text runs onto the .jumbotron div.

Thanks guys, I know its a lot, but hopefully someone can help me with one of these!!

****Here's the JSFiddle**** http://jsfiddle.net/thedonmon/KZ7d8/5/

Comment: Honestly, I tend to hate using background. I've been much happier with an absolutely positioned div with a negative z-index that way, I can do absolutely whatever I want to with it.

Comment: So that seems to work in the result window, but when I view fullscreen result, it shows the original layout...and when I comment out the code i had originally for the background, there's a gray box?

`code`.jumbotron {
   background:url("http://i.imgur.com/5zm8SAo.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
    height: 500px;
}
.jumbotron .container {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute; 
} `code`

Comment: do you have media specific css?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by having media specific css... I just added the code to the container class. Cant figure out why the result is different than the full screen result

Answer (score 0):

Yes the OTF files need to be on the server if you are going to be accessing them from different machines. You should have them loaded on the server so that everyone can see them, not just on your local machine. Unless they are taken from Google-fonts, you can use their API.. https://www.google.com/fonts

As for the for images part, I created a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/sburke0708/KZ7d8/18/ I think what you are looking for is the `-webkit-transform:` properties. Make sure you add the others prefixes for the inclusion of other browsers.

The last part you want to check out media queries. These re-size your content specific to your needs. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries Media queries typically go at the end of your CSS to resize specific elements to avoid this problem.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I knew getting the fonts online wasn't that simple.  I guess for now, the default or Arial will do until i get the server up (any guides on this?).

Also thanks for the JSFiddle, so can I include text overlay as you mouse over it with this property (I figured the fade is just the opacity)?

Comment: To be clear, .otf files are files that are from your local machine. Check out http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/ to see the difference between them.
Create a fonts directory in with your project and point the url to /fonts ex: url('./fonts/webfont.woff') format('woff')

Comment: Got it. Gotta get a server up ASAP haha